# Print data on Zebra printer from Android via bluetooth

Tags: android, encoding, zebra-printers

I use Zebra QL320 plus printer. Fonts was loaded from Win7(sys. encoding CP1251).
When I send text from Android via bluetooth to printer in russian lng:

```
! 0 200 200 200 1
ENCODING UTF-8
TEXT 14 0 20 80 Привет мир
PRINT
```

I have in result something like this:

> РџСЂРёРІРµС‚ РјРёСЂ

How I can fix this?

Comment: P.S. when I send this commands from Label_Vista via USB, russian text print fine.

Comment: read the printer's manuals for it

Comment: Search in printer manual and CPCL zebra manual... I cant find. If you show me where or how I can do this, I will be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: ok let me try , please tell me the model number and name of your printer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working example:

```
public void bluetoothSendData(String text){
    bluetooth_adapter.cancelDiscovery();
    if (socket_connected) {
        try {
            OutputStream o_stream = socket.getOutputStream();               
            o_stream.write(decodeText(text, "CP1251"));
            Log.i("emi", "Data was sended.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            bluetoothCloseConnection();
            Log.i("emi", "Send data error: " + e);
        }
    } else {
        Log.i("emi", "Bluetooth device not connected.");
    }
}

private byte[] decodeText(String text, String encoding) throws CharacterCodingException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
    Charset charset = Charset.forName(encoding);
    CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
    CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
    ByteBuffer bbuf = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(text));
    CharBuffer cbuf = decoder.decode(bbuf);
    String s = cbuf.toString();
    return s.getBytes(encoding);
}
```

How I understend, this examle will be work in Fonts what was loaded from OS with encoding CP1251.

Comment: Hi there, I am facing the same problem. I am using android sdk ZebraPrinterConnection and ZebraPrinter objects. I cannot see any method for opening the OutputStream. What type of object is the socket in your example??

Comment: I dont using ZebraPrinterConnection. Only android BluetoothSocket - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html.

Comment: Thanks mate, I made the connection with bluetooth API and now it's working. I also decompiled the sdk from Zebra and they are just ignoring everything related to encodings :-(

Comment: @smie you had tried to print arbic text i had tried but it will not print if you can then pls help

Answer (score 3):

I have solved it using in the OutputStream of BluetoothSocket an encodint to ISO-8859-1 for printing Spanish characters.

```
      outputStream.write(cpclData.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Maybe you have to use a special russian ISO charset

Answer (score 1):

What encoding is Russian in? Are you sending this as a String in Java?  You have to form up your string with the right encoding.  Try debugging the app and getting the bytes from the string you are sending and make sure the bytes are correct

[Check out the Sun encoding stuff here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html)

Comment: Unfortunately this is no encoding. I download Zebra Android app(http://www.zebra.com/android/ZebraUtilities.apk) and try print russian text. Result the same.

Comment: The Zebra Android App won't necessarily wrap strings in the proper encoding. How are you sending the string above in Android? Using the Zebra SDK for android? Or as bytes? if you do getBytes() on the string above, are you passing in the right encoding to getBytes("utf-8")?  It might be blasting the encoding before it goes to the printer.

Comment: I try use getBytes("UTF-8"), but its not help. Next step was change encoding using CharsetDecoder and CharsetEncoder, and its help. Russian text was print correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
BServico.write(new byte[] { 28, 46 }); //Cancels Chinese character mode

//TEST
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    String text = String.format("%d - %s - çüáéíóúñåæø\n", i, Integer.toHexString(i));

    BServico.write(new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x74, (byte)i });

    try {
        BServico.write(text.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //
    }
}
```

[image]
    Correct Code Page for me
    BServico.write(new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x74, **0x10** });