# How can I set encoding in bluetooth printer

Tags: java, android, character-encoding, mojibake

In my android app, I use bluetooth PrinterInstance, with the following code:

```
  _Printer.init();
  _Printer.printText(" ... a string that contains '\n' characters ... ");
  _Printer.setPrinter(PrinterConstants.Command.PRINT_AND_WAKE_PAPER_BY_LINE, 2);
```

on some printer models, some white-space characters (the string " : " - space, colon, space) are displayed as ú|| (u acute and double bar characters)

probably Mojibake problem - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake

How can I fix it?

Is it encoding problem? if so, Is there a way to "force" printer encoding?

[image]

Comment: What printer models are affected? And are you sure that the problematic sequence is *space*, *colon*, *space* and not some control characters (like non-breaking space)? And why do you mention *contains '\n' characters*? Has it something to do with the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732546/print-data-on-zebra-printer-from-android-via-bluetooth